# Whats the best JSON JavaScript polyfill

Tags: javascript, json, google-closure, polyfills

I am looking for a JSON polyfill (for JSON support in older browsers) that I can use in some JavaScript I'm writing. I've looked and found JSON2 and JSON3 are quite popular and I've read that JSON3 is meant to be a drop in replacement for JSON2 but I was wondering if these are the best polyfills out there?

The only problem I have with JSON3 is that when I run the google closure lint checks over the JSON3 library it complains about for loops not defining a body: 
`If this if/for/while really shouldn't have a body, use {}`

Should the fact that the js-lint is showing warnings put me off using this polyfill as when I compile my library it makes it look like my library has these problems as I'm packaging it up together to simplify it for people downloading my javascript.

Comment: Why are you linting third-party libraries?

Comment: I'm using require.js optimizer to combine the polyfills into a single file with my own JavaScript code. This is so that our customers only have to download one javascript file which will have all the dependencies included with it and the global namespace won't be polluted by any of these polyfills.
Therefore when I run the google closure over the combined files it's including the polyfill and so it looks like my library has lint issues when it's the polyfill that I've included with the actual problems

Answer (score 3):

You can use the JSON library provided by Douglas Crockford.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.

You can include it unconditionally, and it adds JSON.parse and JSON.stringify only if there isn't one defined yet.

Comment: I've looked at this one but isn't the JSON3 polyfill mean't to be a replacement for this library? In which case which is better this library which is using older standards for JavaScript but has no lint issues or using the newer JSON3 but having to have the lint issues show up